# Chosen library not working

Tags: 7, theming

I installed chosen module and the library v1.8.3.

Jquery update is 1.10

Libraries is installed and enabled as well.

I get this error on the console when I try to use a select list with chosen:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.selected_item.off is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the [Chosen library](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) version 1.8.3 (released Jan on 22 2018) is a little bit too far ahead of the [Chosen module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) version 7.x-2.1 (released on Mar 23 2017).

Replace the library by an older [release](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases) (preferably [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/tag/v1.1.0)) and it should work.

---

From the Chosen module's `README.txt`:

> ```
> -- INSTALLATION --
>
>   1. Download the Chosen jQuery plugin
>   (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ version 1.1.0 is recommended)
>   and extract the file under sites/all/libraries.
>   2. ...
> ```

Comment: Hi. Tried with version 1.1.0
Still doesn't work, same console error. Tried to install chosen module again but nothing...

Comment: @Drii7 – Please ensure to flush all caches (Drupal, Browser) multiple times.

Comment: Funny - tried with safari and it works. Maybe is the chrome cache! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Drii7 – Disable Chrome cache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development